# How to make VIP users writable in firebase and firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security

Firestore needs vip3 (users->uid->vip3 (Figure 1)) to write to a specific collection "post", while other collections can be written and read without vip3,
My figure 1 Firestore is as shown:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrHNI.png)

This is the currently written rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    function isVipUser(rsc) {
    return rsc.data.vip == 3;
    }

    match /Users/{userId} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated();
    allow create, update: if isAuthenticated() && isVipUser(request.resource)
    }
}
}
```

How to write to achieve it, the database needs VIP3 (id->uid->Profile->vip3 (Figure 2)) to write to a specific collection "post", and other collections can be written and read without VIP3,
My figure 2 database is as shown:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYZYR.png)

This is the currently written rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Create a custom claim for each role or group
        // you want to leverage
        ".write":"data.child('ID').child(auth.uid).child('Profile').child('vip').val() === 3",
        ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.token.reader == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what did u try so far?

Comment: ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP3').val() == 'Yes'",
            ".write": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP3').val() == 'Yes'"

Answer (score 0):

here's how u could achieve that:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    function isVipUser(rsc) {
    return rsc.data.vip == 3;
    }

    match /Users/{userId} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated();
    allow create, update: if isAuthenticated() && isVipUser(request.resource)
    }

}
```

Comment: I followed your method and modified the path firestore "match /ID/{userId}/{userProfile} {" but still can't achieve it, can't write

Comment: match /Users/{userId}/{userProfile} {

Comment: I was wrong with how your DB is structured. Edited. This should work now

Comment: I don't know why, he still won't write to me

Comment: Excuse me, if it conforms to the VIP3 rule, can all firestores be writable, or only the Users collection

Comment: What if I want vip3 to be able to write the content of the "post" collection? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This rule doesn't match your data structure:

```
data.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP3').val() == 'Yes'
```

In your data structure there is a child named `vip` (all lowercase, no `3` in the key) with a numeric value of `3`. There's also no top-level node `users`, but rather `ID`.

So the correct check would be:

```
data.child('ID').child(auth.uid).child('vip').val() === 3
```

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Create a custom claim for each role or group
        // you want to leverage
        ".write":"data.child('ID').child(auth.uid).child('Profile').child('vip').val() === 3",
        ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.token.reader == true"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Note that the 2 posted pictures aren’t aligned with the way they’re structured, pretty confusing

Comment: Can't write, what part am I wrong?

Comment: @gil: is that a comment about my answer, or did you mean to comment on the question?

Comment: @ERIC  I'm not sure what you mean there. Did the explanation of the problems in my answer make sense? Does it make sense how the rule I have at the bottom would address those problems?

Comment: Both I guess, in the first pic it’s structured as u suggested though in the second one it's structured differently. Btw, the code line u wrote is a way to write firestore rule? I’m not familiar with it

Comment: I wrote the question so it should be more detailed, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @gil: I ignored the Firestore part of the question, and only answered the Realtime Database rules.

Comment: @ERIC: You've now changed the question in a way that makes my answer meaningless. Please revert that change, and only provide the additional information as an update. Also: did the explanation of the problems in my answer make sense? Does it make sense how the rule I have at the bottom would address those problems (though you may have more problems remaining after that)?

Comment: I followed your method to the above problem, but it doesn't work (picture 1, picture 2 can't write and read), I don't know where the problem is, so I changed the question, so that I can better distinguish what needs to be modified, It may be a translation problem, thank you very much for your help